# Squarespace Donation Submit Redirect with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, squarespace

I have two separate donation forms that need to redirect to their own custom 'Thank You' pages once submitted. Squarespace does not give you the option to do this and instead defaults to a preset, generated page. I believe what I am looking for--and I could be wrong--is some custom Javascript that can handle the request.

Below is the HTML for the first form:

https://secure.squarespace.com/commerce/donate?donatePageId=56a99e1557eb8df616ef2dad

```
<div class="left-column-wrapper">
  <div id="form-wrapper”>
    <div id="yui_3_17_2_1_1480624209818_107" class="yui3-widget sqs-widget sqs-checkout-form”>
            <div id="yui_3_17_2_1_1480624209818_109" class="sqs-checkout-form-content”>
                <form action="/commerce/submit-donation?crumb=BF2bsTsJ-mjNZmFjMjkxZDUyMDVlNmMxYjZmYjM4NjFiNWQ4MjU0" method="POST”>
                        <input type="hidden" name="customFormSubmission”>
                    <div id="yui_3_17_2_1_1480624209818_163" class="yui3-widget sqs-widget sqs-checkout-form-section card sqs-checkout-form-address sqs-checkout-form-payment editing sqs-checkout-form-payment-focused”>
                        <div id="yui_3_17_2_1_1480624209818_165" class="sqs-checkout-form-payment-content”>
                            <div class="title">
                            <fieldset id="yui_3_17_2_1_1480624209818_836">
                                <div class="subtitle">Billing Address</div>
                                    <!-- bill to shipping -->
                                    <!-- Billing Information —>
                                <div id="billing-address">
                                <div id=“credit-card”>…</div>
                                <div class="subtitle">Secure Payment</div>
                                 <!--
                                    Credit Card Fields
                                        NOTA BENE: These INPUTs are left without 'name' because we ABSOLUTELY must NOT
                                    transmit these values to our own servers.
                                 -->
                                <div id="credit-card”>…</div>
                                <!-- Secure payment conditions -->
                                <div id="comfort”>…</div>
                                <!-- Place Order -->
                                <div id="place-order">
                                    <div id="place-order-button" class="button continue-button" value="Place Order">SECURE DONATION</div>
                                    <div class="wait-in-queue-message" style="display: none”>…</div>
                                    <!-- hidden field to convey the Stripe Token so we may submit the charge -->
                                    <input name="stripeToken" type="hidden">
                                    <!-- optional hidden fields -->
                                        <input name="donationAmountCents" type="hidden">
                                        <input name="donatePageId" type="hidden">
                                        <input name="email" type="hidden">
                                        <input name="phone" type="hidden">
                                        <input name="joinMailingList" type="hidden">
                                    </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the beginning of the HTML for the second form (just to show a comparison for the differences):

https://secure.squarespace.com/commerce/donate?donatePageId=583c8b80d2b8571174b04cc8

```
<div class="left-column-wrapper">
  <div id="form-wrapper”>
    <div id="yui_3_17_2_1_1480625072856_106" class="yui3-widget sqs-widget sqs-checkout-form”>
            <div id="yui_3_17_2_1_1480625072856_108" class="sqs-checkout-form-content”>
                <form action="/commerce/submit-donation?crumb=BF2bsTsJ-mjNZmFjMjkxZDUyMDVlNmMxYjZmYjM4NjFiNWQ4MjU0" method="POST”>
                        <input type="hidden" name="customFormSubmission”>
                    <div id="yui_3_17_2_1_1480625072856_162" class="yui3-widget sqs-widget sqs-checkout-form-section card sqs-checkout-form-address sqs-checkout-form-payment editing sqs-checkout-form-payment-focused”>
                        <div id="yui_3_17_2_1_1480625072856_164" class="sqs-checkout-form-payment-content”>
                            <div class="title">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you read their documentation on [URL redirects?](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815308-Creating-URL-redirects)

Comment: Hi Mike,

Thanks for the response. I did indeed and tested it out, however the redirects do not work with the Donation Form buttons. When you click a donation button, it is sort of like purchasing a product instead of using the form block :-/

Any other thoughts?

Thanks :)